# Ubuntu Install Partitions - automatic is not working

Tags: installation, partitioning

So I'm trying to install ubuntu on a vm...
I've come to the installation type page and I tried to just use the "erase disk and install ubuntu" option...  When I do this it's saying that some of the partitions are too small and I have to go back and change them.  I've installed ubuntu a few times and this has never happened.  Any ideas how I can install and do I need to change anything?
I'm a fairly virgin user so I have no idea what to do...

Comment: Can you tell us the sizes of the partitions you've created, along with what kinds of partition you've made? If possible, please update your question with these details :)

Answer (score 0):

Which VM do you use? If I recall correctly you usually give the OS some kind of virtual partition when you insall it on a VM (VirtualBox usually asks for it before the installation). Probably your Ubuntu partition is too small to install the OS. I assume you have enough space on your hard drive to install it?